# Can Sublimetext2 execude ruby code and show the results within the document like Textmate?

Tags: ruby, textmate, sublimetext2, execution

Textmate allows to run code within the document and show the results irb-style:

```
1+1 # =>
```

Run the code (and I don't remember the shortcut)

```
1+1 # => 2
```

The behavior is triggered by adding a comment of the format:

```
# =>
```

immediately after a ruby expression and then using the magic shortcut.

My question is, 1, what is the Textmate shortcut and the 2, is there a way to achieve the same functionality in SublimeText2?

EDIT: The TextMate shortcut is Ctrl+Shift+Apple+E (Execute and update "#=>" markers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the Sublime Ruby Eval extension does just that:

https://github.com/jugyo/SublimeRubyEval

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this is answer to youre second question:
https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL

Comment: Seems like this is the closest one... TextMate is so much nicer, integrating the results in the same document.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use [Ruby Markers](https://github.com/mmims/sublime-text-2-ruby-markers).

```
A Sublime Text 2 plugin to execute ruby code and update # => markers with the results using the xmpfilter component of rcodetools.
```

Capturing STDOUT

```
3.times { puts "Hello World!" }
# >> Hello World!
# >> Hello World!
# >> Hello World!
```

Code Annotation

```
def fib(n)
    n < 2 ? n : fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
end

fib(11)     # => 89
fib(23)     # => 28657
```